# How to rewrite frontend url in yii2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii2

I am trying to remove frontend from my url address. My url address is before rewriting **localhost/abc/frontend/home/index.php** and want **localhost/abc/** I tried to do this by using .htaccess and I did but when I use htaccess it render me index.php for all menus.. my menus are store in

```
views
|
|--home|
       |--menus
```

My file structure is like this ..

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

Above codes are of .htaccess of root folder and 
its htaccess file stored in home folder

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule . index.php
#AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

Comment: The idea is that you set the `DocumentRoot` to the frontend folder, then you don't have to remove that while trying to rewrite

Comment: please share me the code for that i tried many things to do this but still problem is same